# Javascript loop refuses to do a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

My javascript changes the innerHTML, but refuses to add the delay to it. My goal is to make a menu that moves the list items right after each other, but this only works for the first two list items. I used innerHTML so I can see if it touches them. I'm not sure whats not working. I did x[0], x[1].. and so on and it worked. Also another question :D, How can I select all elements with TagName in a certain ID?

**JS:**

```
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    var delay = 0;
        for (i=0; i<=x.length; i++){

            x[i].style.padding = "0 0 0px 20px";
            x[i].style.transition = "1s " + delay +"s !important"
            x[i].innerHTML = "Changed";
            delay += "0.1";
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
       <header class = "mainHeader">
            <nav>
                <ul id = "mainNav">
                    <li id = "search"><img src = "img.png"><input type = "text" placeHolder = "" id = "search"></li>
                    <li><a href ="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href ="#">CONTACT</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>`
```

Comment: Can you put this in JSFiddle ?

Comment: Did you ever check what the value of `delay` is? You add a string to a number.

Comment: Regarding your final question, something like: `document.getElementById('myid').getElementsByTagName('LI')` should be what you're after

Comment: @SmokeyPHP correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that what classes are for? IDs are for single elements, so the OP's final question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @skarchmit Just to clarify, are you looking for LIs that are children of an element with an ID, or are you looking for an LI that has an ID

Comment: @Jason I've taken it to mean LI elements under a single element with an ID, which is what my code snippet looks for. Indeed, IDs shouldn't be being used on multiple elements.

Comment: Here is a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LV9xH/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
delay = delay + 0.1;
```

without using "" as this makes it a string, therefore it will not behave as a number and increment the number by 0.1, it will start becoming 00.10.10.10.1 etc

in answer to

> How can I select all elements with TagName in a certain ID?

use JQuery:

```
$('tagname#some_id')
```

or

```
$('tagname[id="some_id"]')
```

Comment: Better yet, just do `delay += 0.1;`.

Comment: yup that'll do it too :)

Comment: I'd just like to point out that if the project doesn't already use jQuery, including it just to select an LI or multiple LIs is ridiculous